# Why does my project build with the dotnet compiler, but not docker-compose?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, stylecop

I have a .Net Core 2.2 solution that builds fine in Visual Studio and using the dotnet command line, but throws StyleCop build  errors when building with Docker Compose.

I am using the latest StyleCop.Analyzers nuget package.  I have a Shared ruleset in the root directory of my solution that all my projects are referencing for all build configurations.  I am using a stylecop.json configuration file in the root of my solution which all projects  have a linked reference to.  The build action for the stylecop.json files are all set to "C# analyzer additional file."  As far as I can tell StyleCop is configured correctly.

Here are (I believe) the relevent parts of the problematic .csproj file.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\Shared.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <WarningsAsErrors />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <WarningsAsErrors />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="..\stylecop.json" Link="stylecop.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.118">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here is my Dockerfile for the problem project:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Subscriber/Subscriber.csproj", "Subscriber/"]
COPY ["Contracts/Contracts.csproj", "Contracts/"]
COPY ["Common/Common.csproj", "Common/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Subscriber/Subscriber.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Subscriber"
RUN dotnet build "Subscriber.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Subscriber.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Subscriber.dll"]
```

Here are the relevant sections of my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  subscriber:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}subscriber
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Subscriber/Dockerfile
```

**Expected results**:  when building my projects with "dotnet build" or "docker-compose" build, I get the same result.

**Actual results**:  when building my projects with "dotnet build," they all compile successfully.  When I use "docker-compose build," I get StyleCop errors, and the build step fails.

**Error Messages**:

> EventMessageDeleter.cs(2,4): error SA1636: The file header copyright
>   text should match the copyright text from the settings.
>   [/src/Subscriber/Subscriber.csproj]
>
> Host.cs(2,4): error SA1636: The file header copyright text should
>   match the copyright text from the settings.
>   [/src/Subscriber/Subscriber.csproj]
>
> IDeleteEventMessages.cs(2,4): error SA1636: The file header copyright
>   text should match the copyright text from the settings.
>   [/src/Subscriber/Subscriber.csproj]
>
> MessageHandlers/EventMessageHandler.cs(2,4): error SA1636: The file
>   header copyright text should match the copyright text from the
>   settings. [/src/Subscriber/Subscriber.csproj]

Comment: It looks like your `stylecop.json` is sitting up a level from your `csproj` files. It might not be getting copied in before the build, and stylecop is using default settings. Maybe add `COPY stylecop.json ./` alongside the other copys.

Comment: As a test though, what happens during a `dotnet build` if you remove/rename the `stylecop.json`?

Comment: @JonathonChase the copy did not change the output.  When I remove stylecop.json from the project and run "docker-compose build" again, I get many, many more errors.  Interesting.  The original errors are there too, though.  You're onto SOMETHING.  I'm just not sure what.  Stylecop is behaving subtly different in the docker-compose build?  I wonder  if it has something to do with line endings, since in the original case the only errors have to do with the copyright, and I define that in stylecop.json.

Comment: @JonathonChase when I disabled the copyright rules (SA1633 & SA1636) from my shared.ruleset, everything built.  It must be that I have git's auto-whitespace thing turned on, and something is getting messed up.

Comment: It turned out to be the copyright symbol (©) in the header text in my stylecop.json file.  For whatever reason, the Stylecop Analyzers aren't comparing it correctly in the Release configuration.  This actually occurs in dotnet build, in Visual Studio, and in docker-compose.